# Uinavigationitem back button not visible until i click on the left side of nav. bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, back, uinavigationitem

I have 3 view controllers (VCs) A B C. Firstly i present A. Then i push B and then i push C. After i push C, i remove B from the stack so user would go back to A if he pressed back button. I use this code for pushing C and removing B:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nazaj" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; 

    //we push C
    PorabaControllerR *anotherViewController = [[PorabaControllerR alloc] initWithNibName:@"PorabaViewR" bundle:nil];
    //[anotherViewController setTitle:@"Pregled porabe"];
    [anotherViewController.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];

    //we remove B from the stack
    NSMutableArray *allControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

    [allControllers removeObjectAtIndex:[allControllers count] - 2];
    //[allControllers objectAtIndex:[allControllers count] - 2]
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:allControllers animated:NO];
    [allControllers release];
```

The problem is that uinav. item's back button doesn't show on C until i go above it and click it. (on B is OK). 
Is there any good way how to debug it or watch back button title change during execution?
Any other idea?

EDIT: I tried using Vijay's idea:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nazaj" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(leftBarButtonClick:)];

-(IBAction)leftBarButtonClick:(UIButton *) sender {

NSLog(@"clicked left"); 
//back to home screen
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

but this function is not called at all and back button is still hidden until i go over it and click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nazaj" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]; 

    PorabaControllerR *anotherViewController = [[PorabaControllerR alloc] initWithNibName:@"PorabaViewR" bundle:nil];
    [anotherViewController.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

    NSMutableArray *allControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

    [allControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1]; //we remove B
    [allControllers insertObject:anotherViewController atIndex:1]; //we push C
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:allControllers animated:YES];
    [allControllers release];
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code in ur backbarbutton or leftbarbutton action.

inside ur function

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

OR

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```